# How to solve this for loop error?. I tried to add a letter in order, in each cycle

Tags: python

I tried to make a simple version of the hangman game. But when I run it, I can't add the letters in order.
The 'count' variable may be the problem. Any can help me ?
Thank you!  :)

```
word = 'houses'# <--just for testing
word = list(word)
print(word)
p2 = ' __ ' * len(word)
p2 = p2.split()
print(p2)
lives = len(word)
print("lives: ", lives)
count = 0

while word != p2:

letter = input("enter a letter: ")

if letter in word:

    for x in word:
        if x == letter:
            p2[count] = letter
            #print("cont: ", count)
        else:
            continue
    count+=1
    print("p2: ",p2)

else:
    lives -= 1
    print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))
    if lives == 0:
        break
```

Comment: Your indentation is giving you problems, plus, yes, count should be initialised just before the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i wasn't able to understand your point of view about the Hangman but following code is the optimized form of your code and also the my playing interpretation of this game e.g. how this should be played

```
word = 'houses'# <--just for testing
word = list(word)
print(word)
p2 = ' __ ' * len(word)
p2 = p2.split()
print(p2)
lives = len(word)
print("lives: ", lives)

while word != p2:

    letter = input("enter a letter: ")

    if letter in word and letter not in p2:
        locations = [i for i, x in enumerate(word) if x == letter ]
        for location in locations:
            p2[location] = letter
        print("p2: ",p2)
    else:
        lives -= 1
        print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))
        if lives == 0:
            break
            
print('You LOST' if lives == 0 else 'You WON')
```

**Screenshot of the Both Executions of the game (Win & Loss)**

[image: Screenshot]